# MySQL sort by 0 and then from smallest to largest in medoo

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, select, medoo

I am trying to do a mysql sort that displays 0 first and then by the smallest number.

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT id FROM `items` WHERE `name`='Mag' AND `var`='Bl' ORDER BY atrow + 0 ASC"
```

How to write it in medoo?

```
$item = $database->select("items", "@id", [
    "var[=]" => "Bl",
    "name[=]" => "Mag",
    "ORDER" => ["atrow" => "ASC"]
]);
```

This is not working properly.

Comment: Don't know what you mean by not working and if row is the actual column name you have but ROW (R); became reserved in 8.0.2 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-R

Comment: row name off column

Comment: To be honest I don't see why ORDER BY row + 0 ASC is necessary in the first place..is row a string by any chance? and do you have examples.

Comment: for batter sort @P.Salmon

Comment: How is it better? if integer the order by is ascending so all zeros will appear first then next highest value and so on.

Comment: after refresh ibb.co/m5MT7Cb ibb.co/SV9rjCj not sort

Answer (score 0):

You need a two tiered sort here.  Assuming we use the following raw MySQL query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM item
ORDER BY row != 0, row;
```

PHP code:

```php
$item= $database->select("items", "@id", [ "ORDER" => Medoo::raw("`row` != 0, `row`")]);
```

Comment: test this `$item= $database->select("items", "@id", [ "ORDER" => Medoo::raw("row != 0, row")]);` not true

Comment: As the commentor above mentioned, `ROW` is now a reserved MySQL keyword.  Try my updated answer which escapes `ROW` in backticks.

Comment: edit ROW column to attrrow

Comment: after refresh
https://ibb.co/m5MT7Cb
https://ibb.co/SV9rjCj not sort